# Puma crashing after running at 100% for a few seconds

Tags: ruby-on-rails, amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, devops, puma

I've deployed my ROR app at AWS EC2 instance using Nginx and Puma. Now, I have a page in app that runs lots of queries in loops(I know that's bad but we'll be improving it in some time).
Now the thing is, this page is giving 502 Gateway Timeout error resulting in crashing Puma Server. I investigated the CPU processes on server and it shows that `ruby` process runs at 100% CPU for few seconds and after that Puma crashes.

I'm unsure why is this happening, as the same page with same data loads on local PC in 6-7 seconds.

Is this some limit from AWS on processes?
Is this something on the Puma side?

Comment: What instance type are you using?

Comment: I really doubt if it's server related. Try using iodine, it's a server with the similar properties to Puma and it will allow you to test if the issue is bound to the server or not.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the issue after multiple hours of debugging. It was a very edge case scenario putting server in an infinite loop causing memory to overflow.
I used `top -i` to investigate the increasing memory.
Thank you all for suggestions and responses.

Answer (score 0):

Without further information, it's not possible to give an exact answer what's causing the problem.

As an "educated guess", I'd say it could be an out-of-memory issue.